# Length of locally free resolution complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a projective scheme and let $C^{\bullet} = \left\{\dots\rightarrow C^i\rightarrow C^{i+1}\rightarrow\dots\right\}$ be a perfect complex in $D^b(X)$. As $X$ carries an ample family of line bundles it has the resolution property, i.e. every perfect complex is strictly perfect. So suppose $C^{\bullet}$ is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex $E^{\bullet}$ consisting of locally free sheaves.

If we know the projective dimensions of each of the $C^i$, is it possible to make a statement about the (minimal) length of the locally free resolution $E^{\bullet}$?

For example, if $C^{\bullet} = \left\{C^0\rightarrow C^1\right\}$, $\mathrm{pd}(C^0)=1$ and $\mathrm{pd}(C^1)=2$ I would assume that we can find a 3-term complex $E^{\bullet}$ of locally free sheaves with $E^{\bullet}\simeq C^{\bullet}$ by correctly combining the locally free resolutions of $C^1$ and $C^0$, but I am not sure if this really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - take the total complex of the following double complex after chopping off the $C^\bullet$ row at the bottom:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E^{0,\bullet} @>>> E^{1,\bullet}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C^0 @>>> C^1
\end{CD}$$

where we define the map $E^{0,\bullet}\to E^{1,\bullet}$ by applying the  lifting property of projective modules for the map $E^{0,0}\to C^1$ to the surjection $E^{1,0}\to C^1$ to get a map $E^{0,1}\to E^{1,1}$ and then inductively define the rest of the maps using the same sort of argument.